# JavaScript Validation of form issues with return false and selecting via class

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

### Background

I have a form I am attempting to validate using a JavaScript function prior to my forms contents (or input values) being submitted. I am currently experiencing 3 problems:

### Issues

- I am attempting to display a `<div>` called 'speech-bubble' via JavaScript, however (and for whatever reason), this is not working.
- Even though I am attempting to 'return false' via my JavaScript function, my form's submit button still proceeds to execute.
- Moreover, I would like to validate this form using a class, instead
  of an id (i.e.: `getElementsByClassName` vs. `getElementByID`), however
  'getElementsByClassName' does not work when attempting to change the
  display type of a class, for whatever reason.

---

### HTML

```
<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" name="comment" id="comment-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="Your name (Required)" autocomplete="on" tabindex="1" class="txtinput" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>">
    <div id="speech-bubble">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/exc_point_24.png">&nbsp;Please enter a name
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-button" tabindex="5" value="<?php _e("Submit!", "byrne-systems"); ?>" /></form>
```

## Javascript

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.getElementById('author').value;

    if (name==null || name=='') {
        document.getElementById('speech-bubble').style.display='block';
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should POST the **generated** HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding some value to the field id=author, so I'm guessing that's why your form is submitting.

Have you considered using jQuery? It would make your life a lot easier IMO.
Here's a very popular validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Thanks Fabi, I feel silly now. Yep, the code I had in there was recalling the last comment that was submitted, a dumb mistake on my part, and this problem is fixed now. I appreciate it, thanks!